# Invoking Restmethod URI in Powershell Scriptblock not working

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

There seems to be an issue with the Scriptblock which is causing it to not process and I think it maybe a simple syntax issue:

```
        function start-wait4 {
        $scroll = "/-\|/-\|"
        $idx = 0
        $job = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://webaddresswherecodeishosted") } -AsJob

        $origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
        $origpos.Y += 1

        while (($job.State -eq "Running") -and ($job.State -ne "NotStarted")) {
            $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
            Write-Host $scroll[$idx] -NoNewline
            $idx++
            if ($idx -ge $scroll.Length) {
                $idx = 0
            }
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        }
        # It's over - clear the activity indicator.
        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
        Write-Host ' '
    }
    start-wait4
```

Start-wait4 should begin processing the remote script and display the spinning waiting symbol but is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the InvokeCommand part that was the issue, needed to be changed to Start-Job:

```
      function start-wait4 {
        $scroll = "/-\|/-\|"
        $idx = 0
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://webaddresswithremotecode") } 

        $origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
        $origpos.Y += 1

        while (($job.State -eq "Running") -and ($job.State -ne "NotStarted")) {
            $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
            Write-Host $scroll[$idx] -NoNewline
            $idx++
            if ($idx -ge $scroll.Length) {
                $idx = 0
            }
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        }
        # It's over - clear the activity indicator.
        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
        Write-Host ' '
    }
    start-wait4
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the invoke-expression (), can you remove that and try again?